# ros2 mppi controller

Tags: ros2, rosdep, ros-foxy

some days ago i posted a question: How to convert the rotate shim controller and the mppi controller from humble to foxy?

(I depend on foxy and can't use humble)

I successfully convert the rotate shim controller from humble to foxy.
Unfortuneately i can't convert the the mppi controller to foxy because the xtensor library i missing.

What i did:
It seems like xtensor is missing:
This is the output of my terminal:

```
--- stderr: nav2_mppi_controller                                           
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findxtensor.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "xtensor" with any
  of the following names:

    xtensorConfig.cmake
    xtensor-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "xtensor" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "xtensor_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "xtensor" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

This command not working for foxy(only working on humble):

```
sudo apt-get install xtensor-dev
```

I manually added every xtl and xtensor related files into the respective dir. (i compared with humble dir)

But now a new error occurs:

```
--- stderr: nav2_mppi_controller                             
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:78 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "mppi_controller" links to:

    xtensor::use_xsimd

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:78 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "mppi_critics" links to:

    xtensor::use_xsimd

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.



CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
---
Failed   <<< nav2_mppi_controller [33.7s, exited with code 1]
```

Do you know how i can fix this?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You must properly install the dependencies of packages you wish to build. Try using `rosdep install`.

There's a tutorial on that [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Rosdep.html)